# Different behavior while sending AT commands from c# and Minicom

Tags: c#, at-command, iridium

I'm trying to communicate with an Iridium Modem. One of the commands requires to be sent in two steps.

> See 5.170 on [documentation](https://www.beamcommunications.com/document/328-iridium-isu-at-command-reference-v5)

As can be seen in the documentation, there's two way to write a message on the device. The "one step" version has no problems and works as intended. The two step version behaves as follows.

### expected result for two step command

Send: "AT+SBDWT"

Response: READY (Indicating that I must send the message now)

Send: "message"

Response: "0" // Indicating the message has been stored on the device

### Unexpected result

Send: "AT+SBDWT"

Response: READY (Indicating that I must send the message now)

Response: 0 // Indicating the message has been stored on the device

### Software and methods I used

When I use Minicom to communicate with the device, the two step command works as intended, but when I try to use the FileStream class in C# to send that specific command I get the unexpected behavior. (The rest of the commands have no problems)

Here's a really small part of c# code I use to send those "one step" messages that work

```
fs = new FileStream(_portName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command); // has \r

fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // Fs = FileStream
fs.Flush();
```

Note that the command has "\r"

I'm guessing all this is related with "\r" or "\n" sent as part of the command. But if I try to send the "two step" command without it, the command will not be sent and therefore I don't get the "ready" response.

Comment: How are you opening the `FileStream`?

Comment: Also, could you show how you're sending that two-part message?

Comment: I tried simply removing the "\r" from my string command, hoping I would get the "READY" part. Edited for the FileStream opening.

Comment: You would normally use the SerialPort class to do this in .NET.  The usage of FileStream suggests this code runs on Unix and probably talks to a TTY device.  Which has lots of features to modify the transmitted data, perhaps you need to run [stty](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) to turn off -onlcr (just guessing).  Or use SerialPort.

Comment: Does this work if you try `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AT\r");` instead? Are you reading and parsing the response the modem gives back?

Comment: I really hope the documentation is incorrect; if `AT+SBDWT=hello` is accepted that is horribly wrong. String arguments to AT commands should always - no exceptions ever - be enclosed with double quotes, e.g. `AT+SBDWT="hello"`.

Comment: The documentation is correct. AT+SBDWT=hello does work. Also, using Minicom the interaction with AT+SBDWT works as expected. Upon entering the command i get a ready response, then I type the message and get the "0" response. And then if  use the command AT+SBDTC I get the correct message length.

Comment: Just realized that if I start Minicom on a terminal and close it, my code starts working. So Minicom is doing something, changing the configuration for that tty or something.

Comment: You were using your software and minicom together? Anyway, if you're using .NET with version 6 or upper, i suggest you to use the SerialPort class, I'm using it and it works well on windows and linux (my software run on linux and i've tested it with Quectel, Telit and Simcom modules)